# Python syntax: __getitem__ and __setitem__ with input tuples?

Tags: python

I am looking into some codes like below in my projects:

I have hard time understanding the right-hand side of line 13. What does it mean and what type of syntax it is? Is there any document I could study further? Thanks a lot!

```
class LazyD(dict):
    d_args = {}

    def __setitem__(self, name, args):
        self.d_args[name] = args         # line 5

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return get_d(*self.d_args[name]) # line 8

ds = LazyD()

for my_type in ["A", "B"]:       
    ds[my_type] = (my_type, var1, var2, var3)  # line 13
```

Comment: Your example code does not contain the definition of `domains` - did you mean `ds`?

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate . Does line_13 call line_5 or line_8 ?

Comment: @Grismar Yes, fixed. Thanks

Comment: 5. You can test that by putting a `print` in each method and seeing which prints.

Comment: This `LazyD` is broken - `d_args` is a class attribute rather than an instance attribute. Also, it doesn't actually use any of the (expensive) structure it inherits from `dict`, and all methods inherited from `dict` work with `self` instead of `self.d_args` and ignore `get_d`. This thing needs an `__init__` method, and it shouldn't inherit from `dict` at all.

Comment: `my_type, var1, var2, var3` is a tuple literal. It creates a `tuple` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute this:

```
ds[my_type] = (my_type, var1, var2, var3)
```

Since `ds` is a `LazyD`, its `__setitem__()` will be called. The first argument is the index passed, so `my_type` in this case. Python will pass whatever value it is being set to (in this case, the `tuple` `(my_type, var1, var2, var3)`) as the second argument.

So, it's like this was called instead (`self` will be `ds` of course):

```
ds.__setitem__(my_type, (my_type, var1, var2, var3))
```

That tuple then gets assigned to `ds.d_args[my_type]`, so that it can be recalled later. But the class is very funky, since `ds[my_type]` won't get you the tuple back, instead it will call some function `get_d()` with the expanded tuple as arguments.

If you were to execute `print(ds[my_type])` immediately after the line `ds[my_type] = (my_type, var1, var2, var3)`, it wouldn't print the values of that tuple like you might expect, but instead it will print the return value of `get_d(my_type, var1, var2, var3)`.

Since that seems like an unexpected result to me, I wouldn't call this a very clearly designed class - but that's what it does.

Comment: As for documents to study: look up tuples and expanding tuples, as well as the documentation for getters and setters on properties.